# create boolean datatype in C

Tags: c

In C how can I create a 1 byte datatype?

I wish to create an improved boolean type in C. Someone told me to use char type but I don't know how.
I made an enum with both {true, false} but now I need a datatype with 1byte long (could be 1 bit long). I don't think a struct could be useful so I have to access its fields every time.
I think I could use a typedef to a memory allocation but I have no clue what to do to achieve a data type which reads integer and with one byte long (or two bits).

Comment: Since C99 there is `_Bool`.

Comment: Just use `char` like you would use `int` or whatever. But note that a single char may often use same amount of memory as integer, and it may be slower to access... Also, C already has `bool` type, since C99...

Comment: @hyde: There is no Standard C type called `bool`.

Comment: @alk True, I should have been more careful with terminology. But `bool a;` still is a standard way to define a boolean variable `a` in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already a one-byte datatype in C. It's `char` (or `unsigned char`). You can just define a bool as a char (with typedef or #define), true as the value 1 and false as the value 0, both of types bool.
You could also use bools from <stdbool.h>, however they are not guaranteed to take 1 byte.